Connection with SQL Server using NodeJS
The connection string with the username, password, server and database name are shown here:
//imports
const express = require('express');
const mssql = require('mssql');
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(body_parser.json())

//connection string 
const dbConfig = {
    authentication: "Windows Authentication",
    username: "LAPTOP-JTDH0LQ5\\Harsh",
    server: "LAPTOP-JTDH0LQ5\\SQLEXPRESS",
    database: "crud_form",
    port: 1433
};

mssql.connect(dbConfig , err => {
    if (err){
        console.log("Error " + err.message);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Successful Connection!");
    }
})

When I run the code, it shows Server running on PORT 3000 for the first 15 seconds after which it crashes and this error is shown:

Failed to connect  'LAPTOP-JTDH0LQ5\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms'

although the verification details are alright. TCP/IP is enabled.
I checked the connection string again and verified the details with the SQL Server running.
I've restarted the SQL Server and the NodeJS server as well.
The problem still persists.

Connecting SqlServer to NodeJs like simply mean you are going to manage each request that you will have to generate. Why not using ORM like sequelize and just passing the hostname tjhat is locahost and the port ?

Is LAPTOP-JTDH0LQ5 your Laptop's hostname? Is your (MS)SQL server running on your laptop? Is the SQL Server up & running, Is the user Harsh a valid user in your SQL Server, and not your local Laptop Useraccount? "server" should be usally a IP address, if the sql server runs on your laptop, simple use the loopback address 127.0.0.1. Also drop in your username the "LAPTOP-JTDH0LQ5\\ part.
